# Event propagation with React bubbling out of order

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, dom-events

Given the following code I would expect a printout of `3, 2, 1` when clicking the number `3`. Actual printout is `1, 3, 2`.

What is the reason for this?

```js
document.body.onclick = () => {
  console.log('1')
}

function Test() {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => console.log('2')}>
      2
      <div onClick={() => console.log('3')}>
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<body>
1
<div id="root" />
</body>
```

Comment: That's interesting.  It looks like the React event handling works outside of the browsers event loop.  It may have something to do with React's use of  [SyntheticEvents](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Any native event handlers will fire before React event handlers.**

This is how React works with events:

1. It listens to events at the top-level and converts them to Synthetic Events
2. Puts them in a pool to maintain order
3. Dispatches to React components

Because of this, order is maintained within the React ecosystem but out of order relative to the rest.

As explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRo_egw7tBc

And vaguely described in the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling

Comment: So basically `document.body.onclick = e => e.stopPropagation();` is a very effective way to disable every React-event on the page?

Comment: Likely React will process the event even before that function would be called. This could be done in the capturing phase of the event propagation.

Comment: Well it stopped them when I put it in your snippet. I think React has separate names for event-handlers that should run in the capturing phase.